# jScrollPane doesn't load on first try

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I seem to be having a problem that jScrollPane doesn't seem to load on the first try, maybe because my table has images, I don't know.

[This is the demo](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/again/)

I tried all kinds of things such as this:

```
$(window).bind('load', function () {
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
        reinitialiseOnImageLoad: true
    });
});
```

To no avail :(! If anyone knows what's up, please let me know, thank youu!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works for me. But the jScrollPane appears with some delay. I think this is necause you have coded the initialization like this:

```
$(function() {
   $(window).bind('load', function()
   {
      $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
   });
});
```

Binding to the event `load` will wait for all the page ressources to be loaded before executing (html, scripts, images, stylesheets...).

Is there a particular reason you binded the load event ?

You actually want to apply the jScrollPane to be initialized when your `.scroll-pane` element is ready so simply do this:

```
$(function() {
      $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

---

**Edit**

I've debugged the page to check when was called jScrollPane().
I did not know that the table was actually loaded with ajax.

The problem is simple: your `.scroll-pane` does no exist when you call jScrollPane() !

When the page is "ready", here is what is executed:

- Start loading the table with:

  `$('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('events.html', function() { ... });`
- Executes the load event you binded (because the page has actually loaded, binding on window.load has nothing to do with your ajax loading of "events.html":

  `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();`

  As your table is not yet loaded/created, `$('.scroll-pane')` is empty !
- Execute the callback of the .load() (with .tablesorter(), delegate(), etc)

**Solution** is to put your jScrollPane init code into the callback of the .load(). This will ensure your `.scroll-pane` element actually exists.

Note: I'm not 100% sure but it might work on successive reloads because browser caching is involved and by chance your table exists already when jScrollPanel() is executed.

Comment: Thanks Didier! However, for me it still doesn't work on the first try. The reason I tried the load function was so that the scrollpane would wait before all of the images were loaded in the table... However it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version the `reinitialiseOnImageLoad` option does not exist anymore..

Use `autoReinitialise` instead..

The supported options can be found at http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html